# Neural Network High Confidence Inaccurate Predictions

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a trained a neural network on a classification task, and it is learning, although it's accuracy is not high. I am trying to figure out which test examples it is not confident about, so that I can gain some more insight into what is happening.

In order to do this, I decided to use the standard softmax probabilities in Tensorflow. To do this, I called `tf.nn.softmax(logits)`, and used the probabilities provided here. I noticed that many times the probabilities were 99%, but the prediction was still wrong. As such, even when I only consider examples who have prediction probabilities higher than 99%, I get a poor accuracy, only 2-3 percent higher than my original accuracy.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the network is so confident about wrong predictions? I am still new to deep learning, so am looking for some ideas to help me out.

Also, is using the softmax probabilities the right way to do determine confidence of predictions from a neural network? If not, is there a better way?

Thanks!

Edit: From the answer below, it seems like my network is just performing poorly. Is there another way to identify which predictions the network makes are likely to be wrong besides looking at the confidence (since the confidence doesn't seem to work well)?

Comment: Sometimes, this can happen when using a bad initializer. If the initializer gives the weights of the last layer a variance too high, then there is a good chance that one class will have a logit value much higher than all others, which translates to a high confidence after softmax. You may want to try other initializers: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.layers#Initializers

Comment: It's not the case that only one class is having high confidence though, it's just that there are many cases in which the wrong class (could be any of the ones) has really high confidence. This is a text understanding problem as well, if that helps. I am currently using Xavier Initializer, but will try other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your samples are split by a vertical line but you NN classifier learnt a horizontal line, in this case any prediction given by your classifier can only obtain 50% accuracy always. However NN will assign higher confidence to the samples which are further away from the horizontal line.

In short, when your model is doing poor classification higher confidence has little to none contribution to accuracy.

Suggestion: Check if the information you needed to do the correct classification are in the data then improve the overall accuracy first.

Comment: Ok, do you have any idea on how to fix this? Or does it mean my task is too hard?

Comment: I also notice that not all of them have 99% confidence. Does that mean that I should get higher accuracy considering only examples that have > 60% and < 90% confidence since those are the cases when the model has actually learned?

Comment: Basically that means the NN is doing poor classification. The suggestion is to improve the overall accuracy first.

Comment: I was hoping to not consider the cases where the network is not confident in order to get a higher accuracy, since I am using these predictions for another task. If I am unable to improve the overall accuracy, do you have any other suggestions on how to identify which predictions are likely to be wrong automatically?

Comment: I would investigate the problem a bit further, ask yourself what accuracy can a human expert achieve.